# Uploading documents on amazon cloud search?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudsearch

can we upload files(text, pdf etc.) on AWS Cloud Search using API? I read its documentation but I didn't get any reference on

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/SvcIntro.html?r=130.

Or do I have to create SDF which contains extracted text from documents.

Comment: This question seems to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to send files directly via API. It is only AWS Management Console which converts files (.txt, .pdf, .csv etc) to SDF (Search Data Format) during upload. Here is the official reference http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/senddata.html

But you can covert your files to SDF using [command line tool](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/CLTGenerateSDF.html) and then submit for indexing.

Comment: I found this a bit confusing. You can upload SDF formatted data to cloud search using the API (Very bottom here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/senddata.html)

Comment: Yes, you can upload SDF documents to cloud search but not the raw .txt, .pdf etc files.

Comment: What is the command to convert csv to json? Dead link btw

Answer (score 0):

We cannot directly upload files on aws cloud search using api. You just need to upload the data t your domain from the domain dashboard and it will be automatically converted to SDF format during upload process by the amazon cloudsearch conolse.